# jQuery detect user actions on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to track user actions on a page using jQuery. 
I track now the $(document).ready event. I would like to track if the user navigated to another page. 
Can I do that using jQuery?

Comment: If you mean user type different address in the browser, the only way is using the `onunload` event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
     var navigatedUrl = $(this).attr('href');
     // do something with url here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also `$(window).unload`. Though it seems easier if you were just to track the movement via a session id and log the page views on the server.